# Powershell Excel Cells Not Colored As Expected

Tags: excel, powershell

I am dynamically adding text to an Excel spreadsheet at the end of the rows by specifying

```
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Add()
$lastRow = $ws.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
```

I can add data, but now I'd like to format the two header columns

[image]

This is my code

```
$ws.Range("A$lastRow:B$lastRow").interior.colorindex = 11
$ws.Range("A$lastRow:B$lastRow").Font.colorindex = 6
```

This is the output

[image]

How to format the cell with "Number of Computers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the root of your problem is that PowerShell thinks that you are scoping your variable because you have a dollar sign, followed by text, and then a colon. Example:

```psh
$global:LastRow
$script:LastRow
```

The simple solution? Escape the colon so that it is taken literally instead of PowerShell assuming that it is a part of your variable. Easy Answer:

```psh
$ws.Range("A$lastRow`:B$lastRow").interior.colorindex = 11
$ws.Range("A$lastRow`:B$lastRow").Font.colorindex = 6
```

But I think there's a better answer here, and perhaps a learning opportunity.

Assuming that you want the entire row to have the same color scheme this can be done simpler by using the `UsedRange` property of the sheet, then selecting your desired row, and setting the colors for that. To setup an example I launched Excel, grabbed the first Excel Document in my My Documents folder, got the first blank row. So here's my setup:

```psh
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $True
$Doc = gci "$env:userprofile\Documents\*.xlsx"|select -first 1 -ExpandProperty fullname
$WB = $Excel.workbooks.open($doc)
$LastRow = $Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
```

Then I just grabbed the directory listing of my C:\ drive as just garbage data to paste in so I have additional rows to work with and format a header row for. I'll convert that to a CSV that's tab delimited, copy it to the clipboard, and then paste it into the first blank cell in column A:

```psh
$Data = Get-ChildItem C:\
$Data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t" | Clip
[void]$Excel.ActiveSheet.Rows.item($LastRow).cells.item(1).pastespecial()
```

Ok, that's all just for setup so I can replicate the issue. The actual solution for this is far, far simpler. We get the `Activesheet`'s `UsedRange` property, select it's `Rows` property, and then use the `Item()` method of that specifying `$LastRow`. We set that range's cell color and text color, and we're done.

```psh
$Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Item($LastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
$Excel.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Item($LastRow).Font.ColorIndex = 6
```

In your example you could just as easily use `$ws.UsedRange`.

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated A with `$lastRow`

```
$acell = "A" + $lastRow
$bcell = "B" + $lastRow

$ws.Range("$($acell):$($bcell)").interior.colorindex = 11
$ws.Range("$($acell):$($bcell)").Font.colorindex = 6
```

The trick was surrounding `$acell` or `$bcell` with `$()`